# Numpy Cosine Similarity difference over big collections

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I need to use the Scikit-learn **sklearn.metric.pairwise.cosine_similarity** over big matrixes. 
For some optimizations i need to compute only some rows of the matrixes, and so i tried different methods.

I found that in some cases **the results were different depending on the size of the vectors**, and I saw this strange behaviour on this test case (big vectors, transpose and estimate cosine):

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

size=200
a=np.array([[1,0,1,0]]*size)
sparse_a=csc_matrix(a.T)
#standard cosine similarity between the whole transposed matrix, take only the first row
res1=cosine_similarity(a.T,a.T)[0]
#take the row obtained by the multiplication of the first row of the transposed matrix with transposed matrix itself (optimized for the first row calculus only)
res2=cosine_similarity([a.T[0]],a.T)[0]
#sparse matrix implementation with the transposed, which should be faster
res3=cosine_similarity(sparse_a,sparse_a)[0]
print("res1: ",res1)
print("res2: ",res2)
print("res3: ",res3)
print("res1 vs res2: ",res1==res2)
print("res1 vs res3: ",res1==res3)
print("res2 vs res3: ", res2==res3)
```

If "**size**" is set to **200** I got this result, that is ok:

```
res1:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res2:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res3:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res1 vs res2:  [ True  True  True  True]
res1 vs res3:  [ True  True  True  True]
res2 vs res3:  [ True  True  True  True]
```

But if "**size**" is set to **2000** or more, some strange things happen:

```
res1:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res2:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res3:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res1 vs res2:  [False  True False  True]
res1 vs res3:  [False  True False  True]
res2 vs res3:  [ True  True  True  True]
```

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare `numpy.array` you have to use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) instead of equality operator. Try:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

size=2000
a=np.array([[1,0,1,0]]*size)
sparse_a=csc_matrix(a.T)
#standard cosine similarity between the whole transposed matrix, take only the first row
res1=cosine_similarity(a.T,a.T)[0]
#take the row obtained by the multiplication of the first row of the transposed matrix with transposed matrix itself (optimized for the first     row calculus only)
res2=cosine_similarity([a.T[0]],a.T)[0]
#sparse matrix implementation with the transposed, which should befaster
res3=cosine_similarity(sparse_a,sparse_a)[0]
print("res1: ",res1)
print("res2: ",res2)
print("res3: ",res3)
print("res1 vs res2: ", np.isclose(res1, res2))
print("res1 vs res3: ", np.isclose(res1, res3))
print("res2 vs res3: ", np.isclose(res2, res2))
```

The results are:

```
res1:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res2:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res3:  [ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
res1 vs res2:  [ True  True  True  True]
res1 vs res3:  [ True  True  True  True]
res2 vs res3:  [ True  True  True  True]
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I ran it and it works. But According to docs, np.iscloseto()  *"Returns a boolean array where two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance."*

This seems to confirm that the values in the matrix are not exactly the same (infact they are close to each other within a tolerance range).

The point of my question is **why the cosine_similarity returns different values in the different cases**.

Comment: `cosine_similarity` is not returning different values in the different cases. it return always `[ 1.  0.  1.  0.]`. The problem is in the comparation way. You can not use `==` with `numpy.array`